# gatsby graphql query yields different results in development vs production

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, prismic.io

these two screenshots are showing the same object, returned from a call to useStaticQuery, one in development and one in production. the development object looks the way its supposed to (as it appears in graphiql) but the image on top of production, the object is really weird with totally different fields, and I can't understand why.

to clarify, the first image is of production and the second is development build

[image]

[image]

Can someone please tell me why this is happening?

here is the whole component:

```
import React from "react"
import { linkResolver } from "../../utils/linkResolver"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql, Link } from "gatsby"
import Nav from "react-bootstrap/Nav"
import Navbar from "react-bootstrap/Navbar"
import NavDropdown from "react-bootstrap/NavDropdown"



const MyNav = () => {

  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
  query myNavQuery {
    prismic {
      allAffiliates {
        edges {
          node {
            _meta {
              id
              type
              uid
            }
            about
            affiliate_name
            author_name
            image_1
            image_2
            map
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  `)



  const affiliates = data.prismic.allAffiliates.edges
  return (
    <Navbar collapseOnSelect variant="light" expand="sm">
      <Navbar.Brand href="/">
        <div className="nav-logo">Global Paradise Studios</div>
      </Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="ml-auto">
          <NavDropdown title="Affiliates" id="basic-navbar-dropdown">
            {affiliates.map(affiliate => {
              return (
                <NavDropdown.Item href={linkResolver(affiliate.node._meta)}>
                  {affiliate.node.affiliate_name[0].text}
                </NavDropdown.Item>
              )
            })}
          </NavDropdown>
          <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/">
            Home
          </Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/about">
            About
          </Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/contact">
            Contact
          </Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  )
}

export default MyNav
```

Comment: Are you getting the right result in the production?

Comment: No. I’m getting the wrong results in production

Comment: Can you show query?

Comment: yes, I edited the post to include the query. thank you.

Comment: Do you have static and page query in the same component*

Comment: no. but there is data from another query being passed into the component with the above static query via props. probably not the best design choice but it shouldn't break this static query.....or so i understood.

Comment: Maybe add the component to the question for some added context, otherwise it's a guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `gatsby-source-prismic-graphql` plugin? If so, then it doesn't currently support the `useStaticQuery` hook. As you've seen it will cause differences in development and prod.

In the README for the plugin you can see how to use the StaticQuery component instead which is supported and works.
https://github.com/birkir/gatsby-source-prismic-graphql#staticquery-and-usestaticquery

Give that a try!